# Safari 7.0 CSS transition is slow

Tags: css, webkit, transition

I have designed a little infinite carousel that uses a placeholder div element (that shrinks and expands), followed by a few images that scroll to one side on a button click, after which the element that moves off screen moves to the back of the queue again. Inside a container div element.

It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but the transition is very slow/jaggy on Safari 7.0 on Mavericks OS X. I've tried a few documented hacks to fix it but can't see any improvement.

I would like to know is someone can have a look at the css below and tell me if the hacks are placed on the right elements please?

```css
#ContentGallery {
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 2600px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.flipPagePhoto {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.75s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 0.75s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left 0.75s ease-out;
    transition: margin-left 0.75s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}

.flipPagePlacehold {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width:300px;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.86s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 0.86s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left 0.86s ease-out;
    transition: margin-left 0.86s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div id="ContentGallery">
    <div class="flipPagePlacehold static"></div>
    <img class="flipPagePhoto">
    <!-- More images follow -->
</div>
```

Comment: You have duplicated `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` declarations but I don't see anything else that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. Will fix that so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issues with Safari 7 in many many places on my website mainly based on css transitions. Safari 7 is a step backwards for what regards smoothness of css transitions. I googled a lot but it seems still a matter of rare interest. Hopefully this will change and lead to better Safari 7 versions in the coming updates. There are also color difference issues…
So I don’t think it has to do with your code at all! Hope this helps a little.